# Typesafe delegation without instanceof

Tags: java, delegation

I have a service routine:

```
filter(List<Criterion> criteria);
```

Is there a good way to **internally** dispatch the method call to a typesafe implementation of a specific `Criteria` without involving `instanceof` and without cluttering the API.

I'd like something like the following (which naturally doesn't work though):

```
filter(List<Criterion> criteria) {
   for (Criterion c : criteria) {
       dispatch(c);
   }
 }

dispatch(FooCriterion c) {...}
dispatch(BarCriterion c) {...}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although it might be viewed as cluttering, something like the Visitor pattern can be used (using the principle of double-dispatch):

```
public class Dispatcher {
    void dispatch(FooCriterion foo) { .. }
    void dispatch(BarCriterion bar) { .. }
}

class FooCriterion implements Criterion {
   void visit(Dispatcher d) {
      d.dispatch(this);
   }
}

Dispatcher d = new Dispatcher();
for (Criterion c : criteria) {
   c.visit(d);
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Internal cluttering is not a huge problem.

Comment: You got two identical signatures in your Dispatcher

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you want to use the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

The wikipedia article contains a Java example.

Answer (score 0):

Visitor pattern is the preferred solution if you want one and only one instance of the method to be called according to the object's type.

However, if you have C inherits B inherits A and you want your objects to call the method for their class type and all inherited (for example), you must use [isAssignableFrom(...)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29).

For example, if your object is if type B and you want it to call `dispatch(B obj)` and `dispatch(C obj)`, you need to enclose those calls with respectively:

```
if (A.isAssignableFrom(obj.getClass())) { dispatchA(obj); }
if (B.isAssignableFrom(obj.getClass())) { dispatchB(obj); }
if (C.isAssignableFrom(obj.getClass())) { dispatchC(obj); }
```

Don't ever use instanceof, because it would not work in this case.

Comment: Huh!? That isn't correct, your example would work with instanceof as well, so there's no reason to use isAssignableFrom

Comment: @Kaj ok, let me be more complete here: 'it would not work when you use generic types'. Instanceof requires you to know the type at compile time, which is not the case with generic types. Such cases are not well covered by the visitor pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
I have only this to suggest with some duplication.
private void filter(List<Criterion> criteria) 
{
 for(FooCriterion c : fetchFooCriterias(criteria))
 {
  dispatch(c);
 }
}
private List<FooCriterion> fetchFooCriterias(List<Criterion> criteria) 
{
 List<FooCriterion> fc = new ArrayList<FooCriterion>();
 for(Criterion c:criteria)
 {
  if(c instanceof BarCriterion)
  {
   fc.add((FooCriterion)c);
  }
 } 
 return fc;
}
```

Another solution could be using following commons classes but it might clutter your code.
import org.apache.commons.collections.Predicate;
import org.apache.commons.collections.iterators.FilterIterator;

Try it out.